# How to run Apache Beam Pipeline connected to PubSub built in Golang on Directrunner

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to build a Apache Beam Pipeline in Golang that connects to PubSub with Apache Beam.

I'm trying to run Pipeline on directrunner,[In the official document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/), there is a description to set the streaming option to true, but in Golang No streaming option.

My question is: how to run Pipeline that connects to PubSub in Golang on Directrunner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current implementation of [pubsubio](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/e568e52b62bc203fad5efb9319747159f73feaf1/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/pubsubio/pubsubio.go#L18) in Go SDK, you can use it only on Dataflow runner. You can take a look at this [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/examples/streaming_wordcap/wordcap.go) to get started.